# Vaadin + tomcat : Guessed User name

Tags: tomcat, vaadin

I've a simple question: i've developed a Vaadin (7.5.0) application, deployed on Tomcat (7).
When I check active sessions under tomcat management, I can't see anything under the "Guessed User name" column.
[image]

I've already tryied to set vaadin session variables, but with no success.
How can I set that username from Vaadin, so that tomcat read it?

Thanks so much

Comment: did you try: VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().setAttribute("userName", "test-user");

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer: I've tried your solution, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Sascha Frinken, the solution is:

```
VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().setAttribute("userName", "test-user");
```